# Get host from Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, rest

I've got a 3rd party service which returns a `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate`.

`RestTemplate restTemplate = someService.getTemplate();`

It has a host set somewhere so you can make calls to `restTemplate.getForObject(relativeUrl, String.class)`. The restTemplate will then make a call to **host**+relativeUrl.

I would like to get the **host** part out of the restTemplate variable.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can get with `UriTemplateHandler`

```java
RestTemplate restTemplate = someService.getTemplate();
restTemplate.getUriTemplateHandler().expand("/").getHost()
```